キューブの側面に重さを集中させたい
立方体のオブジェクトを作成し、Rigidbody等を使用して運動させるのですが、各側面の中心4点に重さを集中させたいです。重心の位置は変わらずに、側面に重さがかかっているという様にしたいです。
子オブジェクトなどを活用して試したのですが中々うまくいかず、何か方法があれば教えていただきたいです。
